# Custom MessageBox DialogResult

Tags: c#, winforms, error-handling, messagebox

I have a custom c# MessageBox with custom Buttons Also, and I overrode Show() method, here is the most of my code:

```
public partial class CustomMessageBox : Form
{
    public CustomMessageBox()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
#region Variables
public static CustomMessageBox MsgBox;
public static DialogResult result;
public enum CustomMessageBoxButtons { Ok, OkCancel }
public enum CustomMessageBoxTxtBoxState { VisibleChar, PasswordChar, VisibleCharReadOnly }
#endregion

public static DialogResult Show(string text, string title, CustomMessageBoxButtons buttons)
{
    MsgBox = new CustomMessageBox();
    MsgBox.txtbox_content.Text = text;
    MsgBox.lbl_Title.Text = title;
    result = DialogResult.No;
    if (buttons == CustomMessageBoxButtons.Ok)
    {
        MsgBox.btn_ok.Location = new Point(86, 70);
        MsgBox.btn_cancel.Visible = false;
    }
    MsgBox.ShowDialog();
    return result;
}
```

Here the Custom  Button's Events

```
private void btn_ok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}

private void btn_cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
}
private void btn_close_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

**Problem is Here**

```
private void flatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CustomMessageBox.Show("Title", "TITLEEE", CustomMessageBox.CustomMessageBoxButtons.OkCancel) ==**CustomMessageBox.MsgBox.result.Yes**)
    {
        CustomMessageBox.Show("Aceptaste", "AGREED", CustomMessageBox.CustomMessageBoxButtons.Ok);
    }
    else
    {
        CustomMessageBox.Show("Rechazaste", "dENIED", CustomMessageBox.CustomMessageBoxButtons.Ok);
    }
}
#endregion
```

When I call my messageBox it throws me an error on `CustomMessageBox.MsgBox.result.Yes` saying

> Cannot be accessed with a WinForms instance Reference, QualifyIt with a type Name Instead

so What can I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not comparing result of Show method with DialogResult.

Instead of using

```
if (CustomMessageBox.Show("Title", "TITLEEE", CustomMessageBox.CustomMessageBoxButtons.OkCancel) == CustomMessageBox.MsgBox.result.Yes)
```

Try using

```
if (CustomMessageBox.Show("Title", "TITLEEE", CustomMessageBox.CustomMessageBoxButtons.OkCancel) == DialogResult.Yes)
```

Comment: Done that, and doesnt work at all, `DialogResult.Yes` Seems to be referred, to the Local DialogResult enum stored in my Main Form, not My MessageBox one, therefore any Expressions done with `DialogResult.Yes` will not work for MyMessageBox,

Comment: Well, the return type of your `Show` method is `DialogResult`. So, return value given by `Show` method can only be compared to `DialogResult` enum member.